# Make material change colour based on Intersecting Geo node mesh

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, color

I followed this Tutorial on Geo nodes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uf_v3RE4F_Y

And have this set up

[image]

However I'd like to make these fleshy wires much more wet and icky. By having some stain like ends, like this. (I used texture paint to show what I mean, I'm also unsure if I want to make it 3D instead of 2D by adding a object to the ends of the lines stickin g onto the surface of objects.)

[image]

I prefer not to use Dynamic Paint by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Geometry nodes can only modify [geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#attribute-domains). This means that you will need to store the position of the wires in some kind of geometry to use it in a shader.

You can either create new geometry (like instancing a plane on each connector and align it to normal of the spheres) or make sure that the connections happen on vertexes you can [store a value in](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/store_named_attribute.html).

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot Mesh to points was a thing,[image]